# C program- Placing an asterisk between every other character without replacing those characters in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

**This is for Homework**

I have to create a program where I place an asterisk between every other character in a string. My program kind of works but it overwrites characters when the asterisk is just supposed to be placed between every other character and not after the last character. The issues in my code are in the stars function and the case w within the main. You can ignore the rest.  I'll place the examples after my program. Thanks for any help!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge(char *s1, char *s2, char *output)
{

    while(*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
    {
    *output++ = *s1++;
    *output++ = *s2++;
    *output='\0'; }
}

void stars(char *as1, char *as2, char *output2)
{

    strcpy(output2, as1);
    strcat(output2, as2);

    for(int i =1; i < outasteriskput2[i]; i+=2) {
    output2[i] = '*';
}



}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
     //int i = 3;
       char string1[30]; 
       char string2[30];



    if (argc == 2) {
    switch (argv[1][1]) {

      case 'i':
        //char string1[30]; 
    //char string2[30];

     printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
      scanf("%s" ,string1);
     printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
      scanf("%s" ,string2);

    char *output=malloc(strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+1); 
    //allocate memory for both strings+1 for null
    merge(string1,string2,output); 
    printf("%s\n",output); 
    break;


    case 'w':

    printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
      scanf("%s" ,string1);
     printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
      scanf("%s" ,string2);

    char *output2=malloc(strlen(string1)+strlen(string2));
    //allocate memory for both strings+1 for null
    stars(string1, string2, output2); 
    printf("%s\n",output2); 
    break;
    }


}   
return 0;
}
```

---

```
What my program does:
Enter String 1: abc

Enter String 2: 123

Output a*c*2*
```

---

```
What it should do:

Enter String 1: abc

Enter String 2: 123
```

`Output a * b * c * 1 * 2 * 3` 
-> There shouldn't be any spaces I just separated it by spaces because the website would put the whole thing in italics

Comment: I would `strcat` the 2 strings together like you have (although this isn't necessary, you could just iterate through them both back to back), then iterate through that combined string 1 character at a time, and add that character plus a `'*'` to a new string. Then at the end (outside of the loop) replace the trailing `'*'` with a `'\0'` to chop off the extra `'*'` and terminate the string.

Comment: Actually on 2nd thought I wouldn't `strcat` them together, that's just another buffer you have to worry about. Just allocate a destination buffer that's big enough for everything, then iterate through both the strings 1 character at a time, at the character then `'*'` to the destination buffer, then chop off the trailing `'*'` and you're done.

Comment: @yano can you explain how I would add the " * " to the buffer?

Comment: just a simple assignment, you're already doing it with `output2[i] = '*';`. I suppose the tricky part will be keeping the index in the output string of where to add it correct. That will have to be a separate index than the one used to iterate through your source strings. For every character read in your source string you'll add 2 characters to your output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is close to the original one:

```
void stars(char *as1, char *as2, char *output2)
{

    char *buffer=malloc(strlen(as1)+strlen(as2)+1);

    strcpy(buffer, as1);
    strcat(buffer, as2);

    int i, k = 0;

    for (i=0; i < 2*strlen(buffer)-1; i++)
        if (i%2){
            output2[i] = '*';
        } else {
            output2[i] = buffer[k];
            k++;
        }
    output2[i] = '\0';
}
```

It creates a large enough buffer to hold both input strings. At the same time, output2 is a char array of the size twice larger than as1 and as2 together, so that it can hold the `*` and the terminating character,

```
char *output2=malloc(2*(strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)));
```

The loop iterates through the `output2` array and inserts a star at every odd index position i.e. when `i%2` is not 0.0. It inserts the character from `buffer` when `i%2` is zero while using a separate index k for the `buffer` array. It stops at `i = 2*strlen(buffer)-1` to avoid placing a `*` past the last character from `as2` and places the NULL character at the end of the resulting `output2` array.